# Can a circle encompassing a continuous, closed plane curve be made to pass through an arbitrary point on the exterior of the curve?

Tags: convex-analysis, circles, geometric-topology, plane-geometry

Let $J \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be a continuous, closed curve (closed in the sense that $j(a) = j(b)$ for some continuous parameterization $j:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ of $J$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, $a < b$), and let $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be a point in the unbounded component of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus J$. Can a circle through $p$ be drawn whose interior contains $J$?

What if $J$ is the boundary of a convex set, or more generally if $J$ is contained in a half plane whose boundary includes $p$? I guess the question can be reduced to the following plane geometric problem: Given a rectangle $R$ and a point $p$ in its exterior, is it possible to draw a circle through $p$ encompassing $R$? Intuitively the answer is "yes", but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: What would such a circle look like for the $J$ being the outline of a "crescent Moon", and a point p chosen "on the Moon's surface" but outside the crescent outline? You can make the crescent as round as you wish.

Comment: Take a look at the complicated Jordan Curve in Ronnie Brown's answer to this MO question. Pretty clearly the answer is no. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8521/nice-proof-of-the-jordan-curve-theorem

Comment: Short, plain version: take the outline of a sufficiently concave shape as $J$ and choose a point  $p$ outside the shape, but inside the shape's convex hull.

Comment: @Z.A.K.: Thanks. I thought about it too after writing down my question... So I'm going to add another part stipulating that $J$ be convex.

Comment: @EvanAad if you stipulate convex, then the answer is yes. Find a straight line through $p$  which is disjoint from the Jordan curve. Then take a circle of sufficiently large radius tangent to that line.

Comment: I have shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4434536/can-a-circle-be-drawn-to-pass-through-a-point-and-contain-a-rectangle) that it is possible to draw a circle through $p$ that encompasses $R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will only address the question raised in the second paragraph of the original question.

Let $\ell$ be a line through $p$, and suppose that $J\cap\ell = \emptyset$. Since $J$ [is compact](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Image_of_Compact_Space_is_Compact) (being the continuous image of the compact set $[a,b]$) and $\ell$ [is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1751539/37058), [there are](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Distance_between_Closed_Sets_in_Euclidean_Space#google_vignette) $x \in J$ and $y \in \ell$ such that the distance $t$ between $x$ and $y$ is positive and less than or equal to the distance between any $x' \in J$ and $y' \in \ell$.

Denote by $b$ the line parallel to $\ell$ that passes through $x$. Then $\ell$ is contained in one of the two connected components of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\ell$; denote the other component by $h$. $h$'s closure $\overline{h}$ has $b$ as boundary, and therefore includes $x$. Then $J \subseteq \overline{h}$. (Explanation: Denote by $h'$ the mirror image of $h$ in $\ell$. Then $J \subseteq \overline{h}\cup\overline{h'}$, since every point of $J$ is removed from $\ell$ by a distance at least $t$. $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\ell$ is the disjoint union of two open, connected sets, one of whom contains $\overline{h}$, and the other one contains $\overline{h'}$. So $J \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\ell$, and [therefore](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Connected_Subset_of_Union_of_Disjoint_Open_Sets) $J$ is entirely contained in one of the two components of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus J$. Therefore either $J \subseteq \overline{h}$ or $J \subseteq \overline{h'}$. Since $x \in J\cap\overline{h}$, it must be that $J \subseteq \overline{h}$.)

$J$ is compact, and therefore, in particular, [bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem). Let $d$ be a closed disc (of finite radius) centered at the origin and containing $J$, with radius sufficiently big that $b$ intersects $d$'s boundary at two points.

Denote by $s$ the interior of the square circumscribing $d$ whose sides are parallel, resp. perpendicular, to $b$. Denote $s$'s closure by $\overline{s}$. Then $J$ is contained in the set $\overline{s}\cap\overline{h}$ whose boundary $r$ is a rectangle one of whose sides is a segment of $b$.

If needed, we can "stretch" those sides of $r$ that are parallel to $b$ so that the line through $p$ that is perpendicular to $b$ bisects these sides.

The problem has now been reduced to the one described in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4434536/37058).

**Remarks**

1. The construction above did not use the assumption given in the original question that $J(a) = J(b)$.
2. The construction above did not use the assumption that $J$ is contained in one of the half planes determined by $\ell$; we simply assumed that $J$ does not intersect $\ell$, and we *proved* that this implies that $\ell$ must lie entirely in one of the half planes determined by $\ell$.
3. The circle resulting from the above construction is tangent to $\ell$. To see this, note that $p \in \ell$, and that $\ell \parallel b$. Therefore, the line through $p$ that is perpendicular to $b$ and bisects two of $r$'s sides is also perpendicular to $\ell$. The construction of the circle places the center of the circle on this perpendicular.

   We can now use Theorem 8.1.7 (Tangent Line Theorem) from p. 197 of Venema, Gerard A., *Foundations of Geometry*, 2nd edition, Pearson, 2012: *Let $t$ be a line, $\gamma$ a circle centered at $O$, and $P$ a point of $t\cap\gamma$. The line $t$ is tangent to the circle $\gamma$ at the point $P$ iff $op \perp t$.*